# lenovo thinkbook 15-iml screen tearing on Intel card

Tags: graphics, lenovo, intel-graphics, screen, tearing

So I bought a new laptop and decided to install ubuntu, everything was perfect until I noticed the screen tearing. first I thought it's from the chrome browser so I downloaded the video and faced the same problem.

I tried the method where I enable free tearing and nothing been fixed and it brought a bigger problem where green squares appeared on my home screen and one of them got me stuck in the sign-in loop. so as a noob in Linux I didn't have an Idea how to revert these changes so I reinstalled it again.

is there any way to fix this problem? I just can't find a solution I tried everything on the internet.

```
  System:
  Host: michael-Lenovo-ThinkBook-15-IML Kernel: 5.4.0-45-generic x86_64 
  bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20RW v: Lenovo ThinkBook 15-IML 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: LENOVO model: LVA/LVAB v: NO DPK serial: <superuser/root required> 
  UEFI: LENOVO v: CJCN29WW date: 06/19/2020 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 44.9 Wh condition: 44.9/45.0 Wh (100%) 
CPU:
  Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-10210U bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
  Speed: 668 MHz min/max: 400/4200 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 700 2: 700 
  3: 700 4: 700 5: 701 6: 700 7: 700 8: 700 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-45-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  driver: r8169 
  IF: enp1s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: b4:a9:fc:6e:59:26 
  Device-2: Realtek driver: rtw_8822ce 
  IF: wlp2s0 state: down mac: 28:39:26:a9:22:ed 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 9.22 GiB (1.0%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Toshiba model: MQ04ABF100 size: 931.51 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 915.40 GiB used: 9.22 GiB (1.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 44.0 C mobo: N/A 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 265 Uptime: 17m Memory: 3.36 GiB used: 1.55 GiB (46.0%) 
  Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you install the old mesa driver?

By remove  old one by purge command:

```
sudo apt mesa purge
```

It seems  latest driver is unstable.

[compilation of mesa](https://docs.mesa3d.org/install.html)

Here older driver:

[mesa driver](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/12/install-mesa-19-3-ubuntu-18-04-19-10/)